# Java LinkedList cannot find symbol size()

Tags: java

doing a graph problem on leetcode. I'm pretty new to coding, so sorry if this is dumb. I tried looking at similar questions, but didn't see an answer, so sorry.

Currently doing a 'clone an undirected graph' question.

After the adjacency list is made from the first function called, I try to access one of the LinkedLists' (which is a value of the hashmap/adjList) size and also values in the next function. This doesn't work and returns a cannot find symbol error. I've checked the docs and the methods seem correct. Am i missing something important?

The actual error is:

```
Line 36: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println(adjList.get(i).size());
                                             ^
  symbol:   method size()
  location: class Object
```

Thanks a lot for the help. I really appreciate it.

```
class Solution {
    public Node cloneGraph(Node node) {
        if(node == null || node.neighbors.isEmpty()){
            return null; 
        }
        HashMap adjList = MakeAdjList(node); 
        
        System.out.println(adjList.get(1).size());
       
        
        return  reconstruct(adjList); 
    }
    
    //undirectedGraph-> HashMap (adjList)
    //uses BFS to go through each node in graph and creates adjacency list. 
    public HashMap MakeAdjList(Node node){
        HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
        HashSet<Integer> visited = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
        LinkedList<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>(); 
        q.offer(node); 
        
        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            Node currentNode = q.poll();
            visited.add(currentNode.val); 
            map.put(currentNode.val, new LinkedList<Integer>());
            for(Node neighbor : currentNode.neighbors){
               if(!visited.contains(neighbor.val)){
                   q.offer(neighbor);
                   visited.add(neighbor.val);  
               }  
                map.get(currentNode.val).add(neighbor.val);
            }
        }
        //traverses tree. if neighbor has already been met, or is already in queue,             doesn't add to queue
        // otherwise, adds neighbor to queue
        //regardless, adds to value pair for this node's neighbors
        return map; 
    }

    
    //HashMap (adjList) -> ListOfNodes
    // makes a node per adjList key. then gives each node pointers to and from the         nodes listed in the adjList value list. returns a node within the graph
    // returns node val 1
    //!!!
   public Node reconstruct(HashMap adjList){
        Node[] nodes = new Node[adjList.size() + 1]; 
        for(int i = 1; i<nodes.length+1; i++){
            nodes[i] = new Node(i);       
        }
        for(int j = 1; j< nodes.length; j++){
            int l = adjList.get(j).size(); 
            for(int i = 0; i< l; i++){
                int neighborVal = adjList.get(j).get(i);
                nodes[i].neighbors.add(nodes[neighborVal]);
            }
        }
        
        return nodes[1]; 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: Line 36: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println(adjList.get(1).size());
                                             ^
  symbol:   method size()
  location: class Object

Comment: `adjList.get(i)` returns an instance of class `java.lang.Object` and that class does not have a `size()` method.

Comment: Sorry i'm not aware of why it does that. If possible, can you explain why that occurs and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `HashMap` variable `adjList` returns an `Object` when you use `.get(i)` in:

> ```
>        System.out.println(adjList.get(1).size());
> ```

As `Object` does not have a `size` method, this gives you an error. You need to cast to the class you expect this value to belong to.

*Or* you can use Java's generics, as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72597663/15261315) by @CharchitKapoor

Comment: @user19327144 refer to [Generics (updated)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) and [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) lessons in Oracle's Java tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Provide the value of generic type in this statement:

```
HashMap adjList = MakeAdjList(node);
```

like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> adjList = MakeAdjList(node);
```

Comment: ohh i didn't know i needed to do that. I thought it would like just like automatically take the things given. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes you can make to so that your code compiles.

1. change function signature for `MakeAdjList()` to be like below, this defines a return type of `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` instead of `HashMap`:

   ```
   public Map<Integer, List<Integer>> MakeAdjList(Node node)
   ```
2. when you call `MakeAdjList()`, change from this:

   ```
   HashMap adjList = MakeAdjList(node);
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   Map<Integer, List<Integer>> adjList = MakeAdjList(node);
   ```
3. once you've done #2, you can call `adjList.get(1).size())` without issues

That should be all you need to get your code compiling.

Without making those changes, your call to `HashMap adjList = MakeAdjList(node)` comes back with a basic `HashMap` where each key is type `java.lang.Object` and each value is also `java.lang.Object`.
Even though *you* know that the various "keys" are in fact `Integer`, and the "values" are `java.util.List<Integer>`, the *compiler* doesn't know that. So if you call `adjList.get(1)` it
thinks the result is an `Object` (not `List<Integer>`) and it (correctly) informs you that you cannot call `size()` on an `Object`.

Additionally, in various places in your code you're using a concrete class as the left-hand type, instead of using the interface.
For example: instead of defining the left-hand side as `HashMap`, use `Map` instead. That looks like changing this:

```
HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
```

to the line below (which uses the `Map` interface name, and also drops the repeated, redundant type information on the right-hand side,
which then allows `new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>()` to become simply `new HashMap<>()`):

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```